# loosing data while moving back using getMaterialApp with getx in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning getX and everything going well ,,but suddenly i notice one thing

and to make it clear i have created a demo

in first screen its showing list of person and while tapping on person tile i am forwarding to next screen when i have placed a button to add as friend like..it saves in friend list but when i move back it clears friendlist....why?

here is my second screen to add person in friendlist

```
class PersonScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Person person;
  const PersonScreen({Key? key,required this.person}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PersonController personController=Get.put(PersonController());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Obx(()=>Text(personController.friends.length.toString())),
        actions: [IconButton(onPressed: (){

        }, icon: Icon(Icons.settings))],
      ),
      body: Column(
        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children:[ Text(person.name.toString())]),

          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children:[ IconButton(onPressed: (){
            personController.addPerson(person);

          }, icon: personController.isExist(person)?Icon(Icons.delete):Icon(Icons.add))]),

      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my controller

```
class PersonController extends GetxController
{
  List<Person> friends=<Person>[].obs;


  void addPerson(Person person)
  {
    friends.add(person);
  }

  bool isExist(Person person)
  {
    return friends.contains(person);
  }
}
```

and here is main

```
return GetMaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
```

and my first screen showing list of persons

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: persons.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
          Person name=persons[index];
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: (){
              Get.to(PersonScreen(person: name));

            },
            tileColor: Colors.grey,
            title: Text(name.name),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i noticed the same......will use only for state management not other functionaliy of getx...like page route and others

Answer (score 2):

When you return to the previous page, "PersonController" is deleted from memory. You can use "permanent: true" to prevent this.

**Recreation of the Controller:**

When permanent is set to false, a new instance will be created on each call. This means that every time a page changes, a new instance of PersonController will be created. If you want to share the same controller instance, you should set permanent to true.

```
PersonController personController = Get.put(PersonController(), permanent: true);
```

**Loss of State Information:**

When permanent is set to false, the state of the controller might be lost with each page change. This means that the data inside the controller could be reset when transitioning from one page to another.

**Memory Usage:**

Creating a new controller instance on each page change can increase memory usage. Setting permanent to true is more memory-efficient if you want to share the same controller across pages.
For these reasons, it is generally more common to set permanent to true when you want to share the same instance of a controller throughout the application. However, in specific cases, setting permanent to false might be useful, especially if the controller needs to be completely independent between different pages.

Comment: One more question..i dont use getMaterial app and do routes with core code...it works fine without adding permanant true...y?